# Shutter wont release after winding on minolta xg-m

Tags: slr, minolta

When I wind it back there is a click noise once i let go of the winder and then i cant press the shutter release so i have to wind again which advances it, I dont have film in it but it seems if i did it could waste some shots which I do not want

Comment: Weird question: Are you wearing gloves? If I remember this camera right it uses conductive skin contact between rings on the shutter button the same way other cameras use half-pressing. That might have an effect.

Answer (score 1):

The normal mode of operation is:

- take a picture → shutter release is blocked, winding is enabled
- wind film → shutter release is enabled, winding is blocked

Without this mechanism, you might forget to wind the film, and get double exposures. Or you might wind the film twice, and waste film.

If you really want a double exposure, there is usually a way to unlock the shutter release.

Rewinding resets the mechanism. When you load a new film, you have to advance the film anyway. The part outside of the cartridge was exposed to light when loading, so you can't use it for pictures.

Comment: You could add that (with typical camera geometries) the film has to be advanced at least twice to reach a usable part, one that hasn't been exposed to light in the insertion process. And the film counter display will need these two advances before it reaches the point labelled "1".

Answer (score 1):

The film advance does precisely that - it advances the film. Most cameras also have a way of resetting the shutter curtains when the film is advanced. The most common way is for a separate lever or sprocket wheel not mechanically connected directly to the film advance lever to do the job. The sprocket holes in the film are what actually push the lever or sprocket wheel that resets the shutter, or at the very least, unblocks the shutter button so that it can be depressed. If you operate the film advance lever with no film in the camera, the shutter reset is not moved. Thus you *shouldn't* be able to press the shutter button and release the shutter because no film has moved across the actuator.

[image]

Looking at a Minolta XG-M with the back open, I'd guess that the roller with sprocket spars at both ends (inside the yellow oval I've added) is connected to the shutter reset mechanism. When you wind the film advance lever with no film in the camera, it only moves the film take-up spool on the far right. When there's film in the camera, though, the film passing over the roller with the sprockets will turn it and actuate the shutter reset mechanism. You can try rolling it towards the film take-up spool with your fingers and see if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there: a bit late to the party, but I was looking for a fix with an XG-M with a similar problem. It appears the two answers above are based on inaccurate understanding of the problem.

*When you wind the advance lever, with batteries in and the switch in the on position, the shutter releases when you let go of the advance lever.*

Apparently this can be the result of an electrical problem OR a mechanical problem. One user was able to fix his body by following these steps:

- Turn the camera on.
- Wind the advance lever (shutter fires)
- Remove batteries (with camera on)
- Turn camera off
- Replace batteries
- Turn camera on

Apparently he was then able to operate the camera normally. I have tried his method with my body, but have been unsuccessful. I see a bit of corrosion around one corner of the bottom, so it's possible there was a water ingress at some point, but it's also possible this is a mechanical issue. The camera turns on and accurately meters so I know current is flowing.

Hopefully, someone else will have an idea!

Comment: "One user was able to fix..." **One user**, where? Who? Was this 'one user' on another forum or site? Please provide a link to the discussion, description, resolution, etc., that you're referring to.